# Sitemap control

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

we have created on sitemap control in asp.net.we have create 'Web.Sitemap' and controls we used sitemapnode and sitemap datasource.I run it. does nt work correctly. It shows blank.

Comment: As jagdeep said, please add some code as it's pretty much impossible to help you if we have to rely only on the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced sitemaps displaying, but with no taxt (and therefore not clickable). The reason for this turned out to be the XML was case sensitive. Changing `Title="` to `title="` fixed it for me.

I am not sure if there is a preference for that.